# Angular Chart.js, how to remove series?

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

I am working on Angular Charts to show line chart in my app. I have integrated line chart using Chart.js. But, in my graph, I would not want Series displaying after chart.

My code of chart is

```
 $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
 $scope.series = ['Series A'];
 $scope.data = [
        [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
      ];
```

and my html to show this chart is

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-legend="true" chart-series="series"></canvas>
```

When I tried to remove Series from code to hide it in graph, Graph is not load.

Does anyone knows how to remove it without any error?

Comment: Got answer while working with myself. Just need to set `chart-legend="false"`

Answer (score 0):

Just set the values to null and hide the tooltips

```
  var a = $scope.data.pop();
  $scope.data.push(a.map(function() { return null; }))
  $scope.options = { showTooltips: false };
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/rt6zoL4k/

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set the value of display under legend to false.

```
$scope.options = {
    legend: { display: false }
};
```